# MPLAB X IDE v5.40 "Link Error: Could not allocate program memory" How do I correct this?

Tags: pic, mplab

**I am new to MPLAB X IDE v5.40 and just finished translating a ton of ladder logic into C.
After correcting all my syntax errors, I am now getting a few hundred errors named "Link Error:"
Below is a small snippet of what I mean: .**

........
build/default/production/main.o: Link Error: Could not allocate section .text, size = 6238 PC units, attributes = code
build/default/production/CheckSoliV.o: Link Error: Could not allocate section .text, size = 3164 PC units, attributes = code
build/default/production/Undocking.o: Link Error: Could not allocate section .text, size = 2390 PC units, attributes = code
build/default/production/CIP.o: Link Error: Could not allocate section .text, size = 1824 PC units, attributes = code
build/default/production/Attach.o: Link Error: Could not allocate section .text, size = 1818 PC units, attributes = code
build/default/production/RetractLipseal.o: Link Error: Could not allocate section .text, size = 1506 PC units, attributes = code
build/default/production/Docking.o: Link Error: Could not allocate section .text, size = 1310 PC units, attributes = code
build/default/production/Manual.o: Link Error: Could not allocate section .text, size = 1206 PC units, attributes = code
build/default/production/LiftAdjust.o: Link Error: Could not allocate section .text, size = 970 PC units, attributes = code
build/default/production/Remove.o: Link Error: Could not allocate section .text, size = 870 PC units, attributes = code
build/default/production/Evacuation.o: Link Error: Could not allocate section .text, size = 506 PC units, attributes = code
build/default/production/ProtectHood.o: Link Error: Could not allocate section .text, size = 448 PC units, attributes = code
build/default/production/EndMain.o: Link Error: Could not allocate section .text, size = 316 PC units, attributes = code
build/default/production/EndDischarge.o: Link Error: Could not allocate section .text, size = 304 PC units, attributes = code
data_init: Link Error: Could not allocate section .dinit, size = 284 PC units, attributes = code keep
build/default/production/Discharge.o: Link Error: Could not allocate section .const, size = 72 PC units, attributes = psv page
mulsi3.eo: Link Error: Could not allocate section .text, size = 0 PC units, attributes = code
brk.Lelo: Link Error: Could not allocate section .text, size = 0 PC units, attributes = code
c30_uart.Leo: Link Error: Could not allocate section .text, size = 0 PC units, attributes = code
sbrk.Leo: Link Error: Could not allocate section .text, size = 0 PC units, attributes = code
remove.Leo: Link Error: Could not allocate section .text, size = 0 PC units, attributes = code
write.Leo: Link Error: Could not allocate section .text, size = 0 PC units, attributes = code
close.Leo: Link Error: Could not allocate section .text, size = 0 PC units, attributes = code
_exit.Leo: Link Error: Could not allocate section .text, size = 0 PC units, attributes = code
xgetmem.XX_eo: Link Error: Could not allocate section .text, size = 0 PC units, attributes = code
malloc.XX_eo: Link Error: Could not allocate section .text, size = 0 PC units, attributes = code
free.XX_eo: Link Error: Could not allocate section .text, size = 0 PC units, attributes = code
xatexit.XX_elo: Link Error: Could not allocate section .text, size = 0 PC units, attributes = code
fclose.XX_elo: Link Error: Could not allocate section .text, size = 0 PC units, attributes = code
xfwprep.XX_eo: Link Error: Could not allocate section .text, size = 0 PC units, attributes = code
strrchr.XX_eo: Link Error: Could not allocate section .text, size = 0 PC units, attributes = code
strlen.XX_eo: Link Error: Could not allocate section .text, size = 0 PC units, attributes = code
fputs.XX_eo: Link Error: Could not allocate section .text, size = 0 PC units, attributes = code
fflush.XX_eo: Link Error: Could not allocate section .text, size = 0 PC units, attributes = code
strcpy.XX_elo: Link Error: Could not allocate section .text, size = 0 PC units, attributes = code
fputc.XX_elo: Link Error: Could not allocate section .text, size = 0 PC units, attributes = code
errno.XX_elo: Link Error: Could not allocate section .text, size = 0 PC units, attributes = code
xstrerro.XX_eo: Link Error: Could not allocate section .text, size = 0 PC units, attributes = code
xfiles.XX_eo: Link Error: Could not allocate section .text, size = 0 PC units, attributes = code
perror.XX_eo: Link Error: Could not allocate section .text, size = 0 PC units, attributes = code
memcpy.XX_eo: Link Error: Could not allocate section .text, size = 0 PC units, attributes = code
exit.XX_eo: Link Error: Could not allocate section .text, size = 0 PC units, attributes = code
......

**Can anyone tell me if this has to do with something I'm missing from my code? malloc instructions maybe? Is this just hardware related? Again, I'm new to MPLAB so I would greatly appreciate any detailed answers you guys can provide me. I'm using the XC16 C compiler btw.**

Comment: Maybe your code is too big for the flash memory? Try compiling smaller programs first. Disable some of the code and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks Tagli. It was a matter of the code being too long for the size memory I had available.